# How to select two keys from JSON that are located in two different layers (array and a string) using jq?

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, jq

I have a bash script where I need to parse certain data in order to make it react properly based on the retrieved data.
The data can be exported as JSON, so that is what I am doing.

I was wondering if I could parse this JSON with JQ to get the data I need in one go.

Here is the structure:

```json
[{"long_message":
  {
   "just":"a",
   "bunch":"of",
   "unrelated":"data",
   "can be":"omitted"
  },
  "status": {
     "message":"CRITICAL",
     "code":1
  },
  "service":"SERVICE_NAME",
  "message":"you messed up"
}]
```

I need to get the values of 'code' and second 'message'. Is it possible?
I couldn't figure it out based on jq's documentation, so perhaps someone who understands it better than me can help.

My current code is:

```sh
jq -r '.[].status.code && .[].message'
```

...and it fails with:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Is there a way to put that data into shell variables?

Comment: Are you asking how to put things into bash variables, or jq variables? (Both are possible, but I don't know which one you're asking for).

Comment: Also, your sample data isn't actually valid JSON. `parse error: Objects must consist of key:value pairs at line 16, column 1` -- that needs to be fixed before any answers can be given.

Comment: BTW -- if you showed what you _tried_ to do to extract `code` and `message`, and how it failed, that would help narrow the question to the specific problem you ran into; we'd know what you already successfully know how to do with jq, and wouldn't need to cover that ground again.

Comment: Charles Duffy, wow, that was fast. I am asking, wether I can put things into bash variables.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, And I think there was an extra curly brace, I removed it.
As for how... I've tried different things but mainly I tried to do this or some variation:

`jq -r '.[].status.code && .[].message'`

It fails with:

`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`

Comment: Thanks; I edited the details from your comment into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUL-delimiting output from jq lets you read it into bash variables even if it contains newlines or other delimiters (which we could possibly see -- consider `"message": "first line\nsecond line"`).

You can do this with `jq -j` (like `-r` but without the automatic newlines), then adding explicit NULs with `"\u0000"`. On the bash side, the practices needed for reading are given in [BashFAQ #001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- search for `NUL` therein.

Coming together, this looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' code && IFS= read -r -d '' message; do
  echo "Got code: <$code> and message: <$message>"
done < <(jq -j '.[] | (.status.code, "\u0000", .message, "\u0000")' <input.json)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be doing just what I wanted.
And thank you for additional reading, I'll definitely check it out.